# Change language of spellcheck for Chromium browser textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change the language of the spell check for chromium browser textarea? I have system language set to Polish and I want to have Polish locale but on some sites like github or stackoverflow I want to write in English and have English spell check for textaras. Is it possible to change the language?

I've try to add `lang="en"` to textarea in dev tools but this didn't work.

It seems that the only way to change the language is to use context menu, is there a way to do that from javascript or html?

I'm using Chromium on Xubuntu GNU/Linux.

Comment: If this is still accurate then the answer to _is it possible to change the language_ is "no": https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389498

Comment: I think here is the answer you're looking for:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/how-can-i-change-the-language-in-chromium

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a dev problem, but just a browser setting. So there is no need to use `lang="en"`
I think here is the answer you're looking for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/how-can-i-change-the-language-in-chromium

Hope this helps.